# Writing data from a file to an Array

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class RF{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        int count = 0;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            //System.out.println(br.readLine());
            count++;
        }
        String []readArray = new String[count];

        for(int i = 0; i < readArray.length; i++){
            readArray[i] = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(readArray[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

I cant write my data from a text file to my new array, the array never gets populated.  I just need this data to write to an array and then delete some items and spit out a new text document

Comment: Don't use an array for this. Use a dynamically re-sizing `List`. You won't have to read the stream twice (which you aren't doing, you're just continuing to read). If you really need an array, you can always convert the list to one afterwards.

Comment: I'm coming off c++ and two years ago I had to do something similar to this and I couldn't remember the exact thought process. I'm just new to java and don't know my way around its resources yet.

Comment: @CinCity Please you don't have to add [solved] to the title. When you mark an answer as accepted the look of the question will show that it's solved.

Comment: Are you using Java 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is: You are reading the file completely once and then reading it again (in the second loop) using the same `BufferedReader`. Hence in the second loop, you get nothing because you have already reached the end of the file.

So either, after the first loop, close the BufferedReader and make another one. 
Or do something like this:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        list.add(line);
    }
    br.close();
    // do whatever you have to with this list
```

Now you can add/delete elements from this list and write.

Comment: Well, here's another issue. When I try to use the List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); my compiler says it cannot find symbol and points the ArrayList.

Comment: You need to `import java.util.*`

Comment: @CinCity No problem at all. My pleasure :)

Comment: Hey, one more question. I'm writing my new data from what I didn't on the list, but my compiler doesn't recognize FileWriter. Is that not part of java.util?

Comment: @CinCity it's java.io -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you want instead:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    List<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        strings.add(line);
    }

    for(String string : strings){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Notice that instead of using a string array, I'm using a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already explain what was wrong with your code, I'll only lay down a different option.

If you're using Java 7 and your file isn't too big you can load directly all the lines of the files into a `List`.

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("path to your file");
try {
    List<String> contentOfTheFile = Files.readAllLines(filePath,
            Charset.defaultCharset());
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Handle exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    //System.out.println(br.readLine());
    count++;
}
```

That is going to read your file until the end without putting the data again.

When you call readLine() again in this loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < readArray.length; i++){
    readArray[i] = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(readArray[i]);
}
```

There is nothing left in br for you to read because you are already at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have already read the file to the end for the counting, you would have to close and re-open it to position the reader at the start of the file again.

Alternatively, instead of using an array - as @SotiriosDelimanolis suggested in teh comment, use a list. This does not require to know the length in advance, you can just add each line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when you finish counting the lines,

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        //System.out.println(br.readLine());
        count++;
    }
```

you don't have more lines to read...

```
    for(int i = 0; i < readArray.length; i++){
        readArray[i] = br.readLine(); // You've already readed them all
        System.out.println(readArray[i]);
    }
```

You need to restart reading the file (recreating the `BufferedReader`) before filling the array, or using other approach, like using a List to keep the lines while counting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        //System.out.println(br.readLine());
        count++;
    }
```

That code is moving a cursor through the file until it reaches the end.

By the time you get to this code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < readArray.length; i++){
        readArray[i] = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(readArray[i]);
    }
```

the cursor is already at the end of the file.

Instead, do this:

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        lines.add(line);
        count++;
    }
```

If you REALLY need it to be stored as an array for some reason, you can use this at the end:

```
String[] lineArray = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```